# What are the minimal number of AWS requirements/changes to the project necessary to deploy the django-cookiecutter project?

Tags: cookiecutter-django

I'm trying to deploy the default Django-cookiecutter project and it is unclear what steps are necessary after building the production image.  It seems like there are a bunch of assumptions about where the image lives (repository), what minimal services are required to get the app up and accessible at the desired domain.  Is there any documentation for these steps?

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to cookiecutter too. I can share a few resources and few steps that I had to take.
You can look at these links:

https://realpython.com/development-and-deployment-of-cookiecutter-django-via-docker/

https://benjlindsay.com/posts/deploying-a-cookiecutter-django-site-on-aws

https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html#

https://medium.com/matthew-wimb/a-full-deployment-of-cookiecutter-django-on-digitalocean-with-docker-5293f31a1fdc

To simplify my process for production:

1. Digital Ocean Droplet
2. AWS S3 Bucket
3. MailGun Account
4. Sentry DSN
5. Configure .envs/.production/.django

Comment: Took a few hours but I figure it out.  I'll try to follow up with some documentation here at a later point.